# word processor with nested numbered lists which can be individually hidden

Tags: gratis, cross-platform, word-processor

Common office suites such as Word, Open Office, etc. all seem to have this capability to create numbered lists which can be nested.  However, less common seems to be the ability to hide individual nodes.  For instance:

```
1. First item
    1.1 first sub-item

    Here is some content associated with the first sub-item. It could be anything.

    1.2 second sub-item
2. Second item
    2.1 whatever here
```

Now after hiding (or I have also seen the term "folding" used here) the sub-items of 1, it would look something like this:

```
+ 1. First item
2. Second item
    2.1 whatever here
```

I have put the "+" before the first item to denote that there is more content which is hidden; this could be a disclosure triangle or anything else that visually distinguished whether or not hidden content was there.

I am looking for a solution which is cross-platform, and preferably does not have any cost associated with it.  I have already looked at Word (which I read is able to do this at least on some platforms but has a substantial cost associated with it), and OpenOffice/LibreOffice which cannot do the hiding/folding part.

Update: It appears that there is a free version of Word for Android but I have not figured out how to hide text using it.